# PL-SQL block the result of the first query as a parameter for the second query

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

```
How can i get the result of the first query as a parameter for the second query.
 the goal is to get the smaller date and apply it to the second query.

 SELECT
      MAX(datе)
  FROM
      datе_table
  WHERE
     datе <= TO_DATE('2022-07-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')




   select name 
   from table_name 
   where datе =  MAX(datе)
```

he result of the first query must be applied in the where clause of the second query

Comment: Please check, for example, [`IN` Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html#GUID-C7961CB3-8F60-47E0-96EB-BDCF5DB1317C). Or [Simple Comparison Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html#GUID-2590303E-81FE-4758-A971-1EE8B798951F), the branch with `subquery`

Comment: In my case in will not be appropriate because I am applying the result to several functions

Comment: Ah, you are writing functions. I already thought you were mistaken using PL/SQL in the title, as this looks like SQL instead. But yes, in PL/SQL you can read the result into a variable and then call functions with a date parameter. So try this and come back in case you are facing any issues.

Comment: @user19427142 Then please check [`select ... into ...`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html#GUID-6E14E04D-4344-45F3-BE80-979DD26C7A90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just max(date), use the whole 1st query:

```
select name
from table_name
where date = (select max(date) 
              from date_table
              where date <= date '2022-07-31'
             )
```

(of course, column name can't be just `date`; that's reserved for datatype name)

---

If you plan to re-use maximum date in PL/SQL code, then store it into a (local) variable, e.g.

```
declare
  l_max_date date;
  l_fun1_retval number;
  l_fun2_retval varchar2(20);
  l_val         number;
begin
  select max(date) into l_max_date
  from date_table
  where date <= date '2022-07-31';

  l_fun1_retval := function1 (l_max_date);
  l_fun2_retval := function2 (l_max_date);

  select count(*) into l_val
  from table_3
  where date_value = l_max_date;
end;
```

Comment: Probably i need to apply it to some variable,so that it is applied in several subqueries and functions

Comment: Probably, yes; you'd declare a local variable and reuse its value throughout your code (see edited answer for example).